# How to select a Cufon font?

Tags: html, cufon

How to select/copy the text which is build using cufon font. I can't select or copy the text from [here: Comsys](http://comsysglobal.com/internet-marketing-products/). I used cufon for headings.

Comment: you might be interested in webfonts http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 1):

You can't select it/copy it from your browser!
You can get all text from **page source** (including html tags)..

Comment: If you disable javascript on your browser you have higher chances to be able to copy the text.

Answer (score 1):

To copy text that uses Cufon to render it simply disable JavaScript in your browser and then refresh that page.

Then you will be able to copy the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that because **Cufon** render your font using **Canvas**.

Try using `@font-face` (**css**), example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DeliciousRoman;
    src: url(http://www.font-face.com/fonts/delicious/Delicious-Roman.otf);
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Then just use it like any other font in any other style rule.

```
p {
    font-family: DeliciousRoman, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Refer to: [www.font-face.com](http://www.font-face.com/)